# Firebase Authentication With Unity - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication for my Unity Mobile Game. I have the code copied exactly from the documentation but get a error when trying to run the game.

```
    private void Login(string _email, string _password)
{
    Debug.Log(_email);
    Debug.Log(_password);
    //Call the Firebase auth signin function passing the email and password
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(_email, _password).ContinueWith(task =>    //error line
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log("Task Canceled");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log(task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("Sign in done",
        newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
    });
    //Wait until the task completes
    
}
```

The error seems to be during the initialization of the auth in this function:

```
    void InitializeFirebase()
{
    auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
    AuthStateChanged(this, null);
}
```

But I cannot find a way to fix it.

Comment: please post your error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize firebase before calling methods.

```cs
FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
        //your code here
    else
        Debug.LogError($"Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {task.Result}");      
});
```

You should also make sure that your local `auth` variable is initialized properly.